# "cannot find symbol variable VK_NEXT"

Tags: java

My code says it can't find VK_NEXT. It can find all the other VK_ buttons just fine, but not this one. Is there another VK_ that let's me use the page down button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no VK_NEXT defined in KeyEvent.  Perhaps you mean [VK_PAGE_DOWN](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_PAGE_DOWN)?